# Is it possible to use C++ interfaces with Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, interface

Is it possible for an Objective-C class to have a instance variable of a C++ interface type?

I can declare a C++ class fine in XCode (it compiles) like so:

```
class MyClass {
    void MyMethod();
}
```

but if I when I try to declare an interface like this:

```
interface class MyClass {
    void MyMethod();
}
```

I get an error during compilation: `Unknown type name 'interface'`

I haven't even tried to put it in the ObjC class yet, it simply doesn't compile.  Is using C++ interfaces at all possible?

Comment: I haven't done much C++ lately, but since when does C++ have interfaces?

Comment: I thought it did have interfaces, because I've generally only used the Microsoft version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `interface` keyword is a Microsoft extension to the language; it doesn't exist in standard C++. That's the problem you're running into. You can't use them in any C++ program compiled with a non-Microsoft compiler, so given that Microsoft does not produce an Objective-C compiler, no, you can't use them in Objective-C.

Classes or structs can serve the same purpose. AFAIK, interfaces are simply virtual classes that impose some additional constraints, so you'll just need to make sure to follow those yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible; it's called Objective-C++.

Simply name your implementation files using the `.mm` file extension and you can do pretty much anything you can do in C++.

However one of the things you cannot do is subclass a C++ class as an Objective-C++ class; instead use encapsulation:

MyObjCppClass.h:

```
#import "MyCppClass.h"

@interface MyObjCppClass : NSObject
{
    MyCppClass *_myCppClass;
}

@end
```

MyObjCppClass.mm:

```
#import "MyObjCppClass.h"

@implemenation MyObjCppClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _myCppClass = new MyCppClass;
        _myCppClass->doThing();
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
     delete _myCppClass;
     [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: It should be noted that since Objective-C++ objects don't have constructors in the same way as C++ you can not use automatic storage duration objects as members, but you can use dynamic storage duration objects (ie you need to use new/delete (as you have shown)).

Comment: @LokiAstari: Are you sure about that? AFAIK C++ objects should be created with the default constructor.

Comment: @Chunk. You are correct. Classes with default constructors do seem to work.

Comment: @trojanfoe :  Any idea how a `methodName(namespace::class)` can be used in Objective C side method syntax?